# How to display Cordova InAppBrowser content into an HTML div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, ionic2

I'm using Cordova for iOS & Android with a web-hosted app.
To open an external URL, we need to use InAppBrowser with this combination of HTML & JS:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.kidzout.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');">www.2.com</a>
```

But the target URL opens into the web view, with no "return" interface.

So, we are looking for a solution to :

**Display the content of the InAppBrowser into an HTML `<div>`.**

Note :

- We didn't find any non outdated solution on the web
- We want to display the content into a div (bootstrap modal)
- We tried `<iframe>` but most of the website we refer block the iframes...

Many thanks for any solutions!

Comment: `window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=no');` On iOS this puts a "Done" link on bottom, pressing it closes it and returns the user to the mobile app.

Comment: @Yougchrys - did you ever find a solution to this?  I am looking to do the same too - open an inAppBrowser inside a DIV container.